# Multi lingual site not working with drupal language switcher

Tags: multilingual

I have set the localization to inherit the cms language which I thought meant I could use the drupal language switcher. I have made an events view. The dates translate when I change language with the drupal date switcher block, but the title and description can only be seen if I use the civicrm switcher block (which I don't want to use). How can I fix this?  I'm using Drupal 7 with Civi 5.1.0.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your CiviCRM version? There was a relatively recent caching issue with multilingual that caused this issue.

Comment: The problem is in civicrm 7x5.1.0